# Overload assignment(=) operator in Pair Template

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

Hello everyone I am trying to implement a `pair` like Template. I have tried this:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
template<class T1, class T2>
class Pair
{
    //defining two points
    public:
    T1 first;
    T2 second;

    //default constructor
    Pair():first(T1()), second(T2())
    {}

    //parametrized constructor
    Pair(T1 f, T2 s) : first(f),second(s)
    {}

    //copy constructor
    Pair(const Pair<T1,T2>& otherPair) : first(otherPair.first), second(otherPair.second)
    {}

    //overloading == operator
    bool operator == (const Pair<T1, T2>& otherPair) const
    {
        return (first == otherPair.first) && (second == otherPair.second);
    }

    //overloading = operator
    Pair<T1, T2> operator = (const Pair<T1, T2>& otherPair) 
    {
        first=otherPair.first;
        second=otherPair.second;
        return this;
    }


    int main()
    {
        Pair<int, int> p1(10,20);
        Pair<int, int> p2;
        p2 = p1;
    }
```

But I am getting the error in the last line of  the overloaded method =. It is not allowing to return the `this` object.

Can anyone help where i am doing wrong?

Comment: What's `T1`/`T2`? They are undeclared.

Comment: You must return `*this`

Comment: s/`Pair<T1, T2> operator = (const Pair<T1, T2>& otherPair)`/`Pair<T1, T2>& operator = (const Pair<T1, T2>& otherPair)` and s/`return this;`/`return *this;`.

Comment: Post the exact error message so that future readers can find your question more easily.

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius i have edit and corrected my question.

Comment: Why so many downvotes?

Comment: @DevendraVerma "_Why so many downvotes?_" 1) Typically, when asking about compilation errors, you would include such error into the question. 2) Or, alternatively, you could just read the error, since it, typically, states exactly what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator should look like

```
//overloading = operator
Pair<T1, T2> & operator = (const Pair<T1, T2>& otherPair) 
{
    if ( this != &otherPair )
    {
        first=otherPair.first;
        second=otherPair.second;
    }

    return *this;
}
```

As for the error then you are trying to convert the pointer `this` to an object of the type `Pair` in the operator.

Comment: why you are returning *this instead of this? and also changed the return type from Pair<T1, T2> to Pair<T1, T2>&/.

Comment: @DevendraVerma this has type Pair * while the return type is Pair. There is no implicit conversion from the pointer to an object of the type Pair. In C++ the assignment operator returns reference to lvalue for fundamental types. So a user-defined class should follow this convention.

Comment: Oh I got this. I was not clear about basics of operator overloading.